# How to fix "Failed to start System Login Service"?

Tags: boot, partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive

I recently expanded the virtual hard drive of my virtual machine running ubuntu. I then saw that before that storage was available to me, I needed to expand the partition of the hard drive. First, I was following a guide I found on youtube, which said to click add optical drive, then click keep empty.
[image]

I then gave up on that tutorial, as I didn't think it would work, but from then on out, any time I'd try to boot up my virtual machine, I would get this:
[image]

I've tried deisconnecting and reconnecting the virtual drive, I've tried deleting and creating the optical drive. I've increased and reduced the RAM.I even tried to creat a new virtual machine from scratch and attatching the virtual drive of the previous one (ubuntu4.vdi in the picture), but everytime I get the same result. A lot of work is stored on that virtual drive so I'd really like to regain acces to that virtual machine. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In future, take a snapshot before messing with the fundamentals of your vm. Being able to do that is one of the glories of vms.